# I can't make a programm pass a test

Tags: ruby

I don't understand why the program fails the test and can't find the mistake. Maybe some one else can give me a hint?
This is the program code:

```
class Fiction_Generator
  def location_adj
    location_adj = ["alternative-timeline", 
       " Tolkeinesque", 
       " Neo-noir", 
       " Alternate-history", 
       " Ancient", 
       " Post-apocalyptic", 
       " Dystopian", 
       " Metaphorical", 
       " Anachronistic", 
       " Leather-clad" , 
       " Coal-powered", 
       " Dragon-filled"]
    item_adj = location_adj[rand(location_adj.length)]
  end
  def location_noun
     location_noun = [
       " America",
       " Japan",
       " Soviet Russia",
       " Steampunk Britain",
       " Medieval Europe",
       " Egyptian empire",
       " Atlantis",
       " Terraformed Mars",
       " Antarctica",
       " One-way spaceflight",
       " Outer Rim world",
       " Set from Road Warrior"]
     item_noun = location_noun[rand(location_noun.length)]
  end
  def protagonist
     protagonist = [
       " Ferris Bueller wannabe",
       " student of metaphysics",
       " milquetoast office drone",
       " schlub with mild <abbr>OCD</abbr>",
       " farm boy with dreams",
       " techno-obsessed geek",
       " brooding loner",
       " wisecracking mercenary",
       " idealistic revolutionary",
       " journeyman inventor",
       " collector of oddities",
       " rocketman of the 24th century"]
     item_protagonist = protagonist[rand(protagonist.length)]
  end
  def discovery
     discovery = [
       " magic ring",
       " arcane prophecy",
       " dusty tome",
       " crazy old woman",
       " alien artifact",
       " enchanted sword",
       " otherworldly portal",
       " dream-inducing drug",
       " encrypted data feed",
       " time-traveling soldier",
       " exiled angel",
       " talking fish"]
     item_discovery = discovery[rand(discovery.length)]
  end
  def adversary
    adversary = [
       " a megalomaniacal clown",
       " a government conspiracy",
       " a profit-obsessed corporation",
       " a sneering witch",
       " supernatural monsters",
       " computer viruses made real",
       " murderous robots",
       " an army led by a sadist",
       " forces that encourage conformity",
       " a charismatic politician on the rise",
       " humanity's selfish nature",
       " his own insecurity vis-a-vis girls"]
     item_adversary = adversary[rand(adversary.length)]    
  end
  def assistant
     assistant = [
       " sarcastic female techno-geek",
       " tomboyish female librarian",
       " shape-shifting female assassin",
       " leather-clad female in shades and red leather jacket",
       " girl who's always loved him for himself",
       " bookish female scholar with mousy brown hair",
       " cherubic girl with pigtails and spunk",
       " female who inexplicably becomes attracted to the damaged protagonist for  unstated reasons"]
    item_assistant = assistant[rand(assistant.length)]
  end
  def inventory
    inventory = [
       " wacky pet",
       " electric chainsaw",
       " closet full of assault rifles and one bullet",
       " reference book",
       " meat cleaver",
       " facility with magic",
       " condescending tone",
       " discomfort in formal wear"]
    item_inventory = inventory[rand(inventory.length)]
  end
  def conflict
    conflict = [
       " a fistfight atop a cable car",
       " a daring rescue preceding a giant explosion",
       " a demonic sacrifice",
       " a philosophical argument punctuated by violence",
       " a false victory with the promise of future danger",
       " the invocation of a spell at the last possible moment",
       " eternal love professed without irony",
       " the land restored to health",
       " authorial preaching through the mouths of the characters",
       " convoluted nonsense that squanders the reader's goodwill",
       " wish-fulfillment solutions to real-world problems",
       " a cliffhanger for the sake of prompting a series"] 
    item_conflict = conflict[rand(conflict.length)]
  end
  def title_adj
    title_adj = [
       " Time",
       " Micro",
       " Aero",
       " Cosmo",
       " Reve",
       " Necro",
       " Cyber",
       " Astro",
       " Psycho",
       " Steam",
       " Meta",
       " Black"]
    item_title_adj = title_adj[rand(title_adj.length)]
  end
  def title_noun
    title_noun = [
       " punks",
       " mechs",
       " noiacs",
       " opolis",
       " nauts",
       " phages",
       " droids",
       " bots",
       " blades",
       " trons",
       " mancers",
       " Wars"] 
    item_title_noun = title_noun[rand(title_noun.length)]
  end
  def title
    title_adj + title_noun
  end
  def story
    "In a(n)" + location_adj + location_noun + " a young" + protagonist + " stumbles          
     across a(an)" + discovery + " which spurs him into conflict with" + adversary + "     
     with the     help of a" + assistant + " and her" + inventory + " culminating in" +
     conflict
  end
  def all
    puts "Your story is called: " + #{title}
    puts "And it goes like this:"
    puts #{story}
  end
end

fict_gen = Fiction_Generator.new

fict_gen.all
```

And the test is :

```
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/Fiction_Generator.rb"

  describe Fiction_Generator do

    before(:all) do
      @fict_gen = Fiction_Generator.new

    end

    it "should load up location adjectives" do
      @fict_gen.location_adj.size.should == 12
    end

    it "should load up location adjectives" do
      @fict_gen.location_adj.should include("coal-powered")
    end

    it "should load up location nouns" do
      @fict_gen.location_noun.size.should == 12
    end

    it "should load up location nouns" do
      @fict_gen.location_noun.should include("Japan")
    end

    it "should load up protagonist" do
      @fict_gen.protagonist.size.should == 12
    end

    it "should load up protagonist" do
      @fict_gen.protagonist.should include("collector of oddities")
    end


    it "should load up discovery" do
      @fict_gen.discovery.size.should == 12
    end

    it "should load up discovery" do
      @fict_gen.discovery.should include("encrypted data feed")
    end

    it "should load up adversary" do
      @fict_gen.adversary.size.should == 12
    end

    it "should load up assistant" do
      @fict_gen.assistant.size.should == 8
    end

    it "should load up inventory" do
      @fict_gen.inventory.size.should == 8
    end

    it "should load up conflict" do
      @fict_gen.conflict.size.should == 12
    end

    it "should load up title adjectives" do
      @fict_gen.title_adj.size.should == 12
    end

    it "should load up title noun" do
      @fict_gen.title_noun.size.should == 12
    end

    it "should randomly generate a title for the story" do
      @fict_gen.title.should be_true
    end

    it "should randomly generate a story using an item from each array" do
      @fict_gen.story.should be_true
    end

    after(:all) do
      puts "your story is called #{@fict_gen.title} "
      puts "and it goes like this:"
      puts @fict_gen.story
    end 
end
```

Sorry for the long code, but i really need help on this one.

It gives the following error messages:

```
1) Fiction_Generator should load up location adjectives
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.location_adj.size.should == 12
  expected: 12
       got: 8 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Fiction_Generator should load up location adjectives
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.location_adj.should include("coal-powered")
  expected " Dragon-filled" to include "coal-powered"
# ./fiction_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Fiction_Generator should load up location nouns
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.location_noun.size.should == 12
  expected: 12
       got: 11 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) Fiction_Generator should load up protagonist
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.protagonist.size.should == 12
   expected: 12
       got: 30 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) Fiction_Generator should load up protagonist
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.protagonist.should include("collector of odditi

   expected " student of metaphysics" to include "collector of oddities"
# ./fiction_spec.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

6) Fiction_Generator should load up discovery
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.discovery.size.should == 12
   expected: 12
        got: 13 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

7) Fiction_Generator should load up discovery
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.discovery.should include("encrypted data feed")
   expected " crazy old woman" to include "encrypted data feed"
# ./fiction_spec.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

8) Fiction_Generator should load up adversary
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.adversary.size.should == 12
   expected: 12
        got: 26 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

9) Fiction_Generator should load up assistant
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.assistant.size.should == 8
   expected: 8
        got: 27 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

10) Fiction_Generator should load up inventory
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.inventory.size.should == 8
   expected: 8
        got: 10 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

11) Fiction_Generator should load up conflict
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.conflict.size.should == 12
   expected: 12
        got: 44 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

12) Fiction_Generator should load up title adjectives
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.title_adj.size.should == 12
   expected: 12
        got: 6 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

13) Fiction_Generator should load up title noun
Failure/Error: @fict_gen.title_noun.size.should == 12
   expected: 12
        got: 7 (using ==)
# ./fiction_spec.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: when you run your test file, are you getting any further output on where the failure is? that would be helpful

Comment: in fact, if you can just copy/paste the failure message, I'd bet you'll get an answer quickly

Comment: Yes, it gives the message that points out the problem part. But the problem is I don't understand how can i fix the part the message says is wrong.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to copy/paste the failure messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your errors, as you have them listed here, are occurring in your initialize method. In each case, the error is the same, 'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)'.

What this means is you need to take a look at how you are constructing your Fiction_Generator objects. In this case, your initialize method requires you to pass in an IO object. So instead of just using

```
 fict_gen = Fiction_Generator.new
```

you'll need to pass the IO object in within the new method

```
 fict_gen = Fiction_Generator.new(#IO object here)
```

edit:

So you removed the constructor method from your code above, now I don't know what your initialize method looks like, so what I wrote may no longer be applicable. However the error is still in your initialize method, so focus your energy there.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, i thought the Io might be the problem, so i got rid of the initialize method and all parts of it completely. And the programm shows different errors now. But atleast they make more sence now.

Comment: Glad to be helpful, if this answered your question, please remember to accept the answer. :-)